# KumbiaPHP, No encuentra los atributos que se agregaron a una tabla (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, php7

El siguiente problema ocurrió al añadir un nuevo atributo a una tabla en mysql.
Inmediatamente añadí la nueva propiedad al modelo, la vista y el controlador, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación pareciera que no reconociera los cambios hechos en la base de datos. Depurando el programa tengo certeza de que la información fluye correctamente, desde la vista, al controlador incluso al punto de realizar la inserción en la tabla.

Tengo una vista donde tiene el siguiente input

```
<input name="comision">
```

En el controlador, estoy utilizando una propiedad del framework Kumbia

```
$comision = $this->getPostParam("comision")
```

El obtiene el valor del elemento donde su propiedad name sea comision

Posteriormente, guardo el atributo mediante el set de un objeto, para lo cual creo un nuevo objeto.

```
$modelo = new Model();
```

Modelo tiene las propiedad

```
protected $comision
```

con su respectivos set and get, el set sería

```
public function setComision($comision){
   this->comision = $comision;
}
```

Finalmente en el controlador, inserto la información obtenida por POST del input
y se accede mediante el set

```
$modelo->setComision($comision);
```

El aplicativo funciona correctamente insertando o actualizando el resto de información.

Comment: Si esta raro, algun error de escritura, alguna ; alguna llave que se te haya pasado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente no has borrado la cache, que contiene la metadata de la base de datos.
Si esta en producción se cachea esa metadata.
Si se hacen cambios después, se debe borrar la cache en /tmp/cache/*